# iText PdfpTable PdfPCell row alignment and spacing

Tags: itext

I inherited the maintenance of a Java application to create invoices. It uses the iText PDF library. My questions concern the formatting happening in the creation of the header and footer in the `onEndPageEvent()`.

The document has the following borders.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 18, 72, 205, 170);
```

The header table has the following characteristics:

```
PdfPTable tHead = new PdfPTable(5);
int tHead_tHeaderwidths[] = { 4, 5, 50, 15, 26 };
tHead.setWidths(tHead_tHeaderwidths);
```

A GIF image creates a borderline as the last row in the header table as follows:

```
c = new PdfPCell(invoice_header1);
c.setColspan(5);
c.setBorder(0);
c.setPaddingTop(10);            
c.setPaddingLeft(10);                
c.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);            
tHead.addCell(c);
```

The footer table has the following characteristics:

```
PdfPTable tFoot = new PdfPTable(3);
int total_table_headerwidths[] = { 75, 5, 20 }; // percentage
tFoot.setWidths(total_table_headerwidths);
```

A GIF image creates a borderline as the first row in the footer table as well.

```
c = new PdfPCell(invoice_header2);
c.setColspan(3);
c.setBorder(0);                       
c.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);            
tFoot.addCell(c);
```

*Why do these images not align on the right-hand side in the document?*
They should align to the right hand border.

*Why does the text in the first rows of the header table and the rows at the bottom of the footer table have row spacing, spacing between lines, different than other text added to the document?*
The text has the same font as other text and no other space formatting applied.

Here is a screenshot of the document
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please share the gif images in question.

Comment: If you inherited maintenance, then check if your company has a support contract. Up to 3 support contacts are registered per customer, just send a mail to sales at iText Software if you want to replace a no longer used contact with yourself. http://itextpdf.com/contact I know this is slightly off topic for Stack Overflow but we have no other way to reach you.

Comment: mkl, the GIFs are the "Description" and "Total Due" black lines. This is my first post and am not aware of how to share the actual GIF files.

Comment: Amedee Van Gasse, my company does not have a maintenance contract, Not sure if it was purchased in the beginning (around 2005) or at the time the code was open source.